# How to copy the source of function to another one in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Let a function test

```
function test { }
```

I want to have function test2 = function test and be able to modify function test without impacting the copy test2: don't know if it is even possible :)

Update: I want to override the original function but kept it under another name so as to be able to call it from the second one.

I know about  $function:test but I can't see afterwards how to use it for that purpose.

Comment: You want two functions to do the same thing, but be able to modify one of them without impacting the other?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve it yourself? `console.log` isn't even powershell syntax

Comment: @arco444 console.log or whatever doesn't matter so I just deleted it

Comment: @JamesC. I want to override the original function but kept it under another name so as to be able to call it from the second one.

Comment: There is a `function:` drive where you can access function definitions.  You'd need to do something like `Function Test2 { . $function:test }`

Comment: @arco444 sure with  $function:test doesn't work

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 what do you mean ? This: function test2 {. $function:test} ? When I call test2 it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Try `Write-Output $function:test`.  What do you see?

Comment: What is your use case? (What is it you're really trying to do, and why?)

Comment: Your question is very vague and contains no actual code so we have no idea what, or how, you are trying to do. You really need to read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) as nobody understands what you are trying to do at the moment.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart my usecase is to customize an existing function for example dir so I want to keep it under another name so as to redefine it and call it inside the new definition.

Comment: If you had your "proxy" function in a different loaded module you could call it be specifying its scope. Just seems like an odd thing to do.

Comment: So the question is how to copy the content from one function into another?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart yes.

Comment: @Matt the purpose is to be able to call the function the usual way like dir function so I don't want to have to have to use a module name

Comment: Sounds like you want `New-Alias`? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176913.aspx

Comment: @JamesC. no an alias is a POINTER to the function so if you change the function the alias also is changed. I really want an independant copy. But thanks, I also need alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to copy the content of one function into another:

```
function function1 {
  "function output"
}

$Function:function2 = $Function:function1

Get-Content Function:function2
# output: "function output"
```

Comment: at least someone understood my question: thanks a lot :)

Comment: This is what the title asked for but the body of the question and comments trail of which confused many it seems. If they have access to the function I didnt understand why copy and past would not work.

Comment: Not sure either...the question doesn't make clear what the purpose is (why is this needed--what problem does it solve? What is the use case?)...hence the suspicion that it's really an XY problem...